# How to read a nested json?

Tags: json, reactjs, next.js

I don't see any mistake with the following code but yet still I am getting error message "item._highlightResult.map is not a function".

```
    {items.map((item, index) => (
<li key={index}><a href={item.story_url} target="_blank">
 {(item._highlightResult.map)(sub => {
     {sub.story_title.map (inhere => {
         {inhere.value}
     })}
 })}
```

and this is my json data: https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=world

How can I make this work?

Comment: Hi There ! I checked your JSON. At the top level there is an object. and it contains an array having key "hits". I guess you have stored hits array in items. Right?

Comment: Index as key is an anti pattern, https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: `const { _highlightResult } = response.hits
        response.hits.forEach(hit =>{
          const {_highlightResult} = hit;
          Object.keys(_highlightResult).map(res =>{
            console.log(`${res} ------> > `,_highlightResult[res]);
          });
        });` should work

Answer (score 0):

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the method of Array, but `_highlightResult` is the object.
You should use `Object.keys()` to iterate the object by key.

```
Object.keys(item._highlightResult).map(key => {
  // Use `item._highlightResult[key]`
})
```

---

`story_title` is either `string` or `object`, so you should check it before using `Object.keys()`.

Comment: William, thank you so much, but how can i reach there before object.keys()?

Comment: can you describe in detail?

Comment: fyi, as Imran commented, the whole content contains the key "hits".

Comment: I mean, how can i check if 'story_title' is string or object before Object.keys(), as you suggested. I corrected the code as but still don't know how to reach to item._highlightResult.story_title

` {items.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}><a href={item.story_url} target="_blank">
     {Object.keys(item._highlightResult).map (key => {
   `item._highlightResult[story_title]`
   if (typeof item._highlightResult[story_title] === 'object'){
    //I am indeed a string
}
                })}`

Comment: use typeof - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @studentUmit : Are you working on a React App ?

Comment: @studentUmit: If you check you JSON keenly, you will get to know that some lots of fields will be null, and at other places they will have the value. Suppose  "story_title": "Moral Competence",  is a string (The one which you will querying about) Look for all the Objets in the array "hits" ... So if you are using a React App you need to do 2 things. 1) Set default values whenever you are getting null and 2) WhereEver you get Objects within use Object.keys() then you can map over like Willian already mentioned :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather yes Imran, working on Next.js, was so fun upto nested json..

Comment: Oh Boy !!! Coding is fun :)  Hope you understood what I was trying to say about Default values... U know this is the important practice in React JS...Otherwise you may get many many Errors in your code... 1) You can try default values with PropTypes or 2) Using || operator efficiently in your code...

Answer (score 0):

You have getting "item._highlightResult.map is not a function" because **"item._highlightResult" is a object not array**, You can try to access directly item._highlightResult;
Please check attached code

```
 YourJsonData.hits.map (item => {
   Object.keys(item._highlightResult).map(key => {
      console.log(item._highlightResult[key]);
   })
 })
```

Comment: thank you, how can i check if story_title string or object before Object.keys as @william_wang suggested

Comment: You can check for string if (typeof story_title === 'string'){ } and check for object if(typeof story_title === 'object'){ }.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who tried to help, thanks to you I sorted the problem out and here is the lines I reach that nested objects:

```
{items.map((item, index) => (               
    <li key={index}><a href={item.story_url} target="_blank">

        {(typeof item._highlightResult.story_title === 'object') ? item._highlightResult.story_title.value : "n/a"}
        </a></li>
    ))}
```